# NH Modified Helmholtz Equation with Robin Boundary Condition

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am working on a quite difficult, though seemingly simple, non-homogeneous differential equation in cylindrical coordinates. The main equation is the non homogeneous modified Helmholtz Equation

$\nabla^{2}\psi - k^{2}\psi = \frac{-1}{D}\frac{\delta(r-r')\delta(\theta-\theta')\delta(z-z')}{r}$

with Robin boundary condition

$\psi - \kappa\hat{\Omega}_n\cdot\vec{\nabla}\psi  = 0$

on $r=a$, the edge of a virtual infinitely long cylinder of radius $r=a$. $\hat{\Omega}_n$ is a vector pointing out of the cylinder.

The solution $\psi$ must also satisfy the Sommerfeld Radiation Condition, which says that the solutions can not come from infinity, only go to.

I have tried the Green's function approach in cartesian coordinates, though the Robin boundary condition makes it hard to easily solve. I have also tried it in polar coordinates, but I can't find any reference on how to use Green's function on periodic domains.

This problem arises from the diffusion approximation in biomedical imaging, and a solution would be of great help in my research.

Thanks a lot !